# Converting timestamp field in JSON using jq

Tags: linux, jq

I used Centos7 and jq-1.6.
I'm hoping to convert every UTC TimeStamp in the json to Singapore time(SNST=GMT+08:00)
I'm currently writing shellscript so I can mix some bash commands if needed.

**The json source**

```
api_result='
{
    "DataInterval": 300,
    "EndTime": "2022-07-25T15:15:00Z",
    "HttpCodeData": {
        "UsageData": [
                {
                    "TimeStamp": "2022-07-29T03:00:00Z",
                    "Value": {
                        "CodeProportionData": [
                            {
                                "Code": "404",
                                "Count": 36,
                                "Proportion": 0.022
                            },
                            {
                                "Code": "502",
                                "Count": 3,
                                "Proportion": 0.002
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            },
            {
                    "TimeStamp": "2022-07-29T03:05:00Z",
                    "Value": {
                        "CodeProportionData": [
                            {
                                "Code": "404",
                                "Count": 27,
                                "Proportion": 0.015
                            },
                            {
                                "Code": "502",
                                "Count": 5,
                                "Proportion": 0.002
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            }
    },
    "StartTime": "2022-07-25T15:10:00Z"
}'
```

---

**My attempt**
I first tried to convert the timestamp to epoch. But it failed

```
jq '
    def datestamp2epoch:
        . | scan("(.+?)([.][0-9]+)?Z$")
          | [(.[0] + "Z" | fromdateiso8601), (.[1] // 0 | tonumber)]
          | add;
    map(.HttpCodeData.UsageData[].TimeStamp |= datestamp2epoch)
' <<< ${api_result}
```

**ERROR**

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "HttpCodeData"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop `map` as your document is an object, not an array. Then, to convert the timestamps to Unix epoch seconds, it suffices to apply `fromdateiso8601`:

```bash
jq '.HttpCodeData.UsageData[].TimeStamp |= fromdateiso8601' <<< "${api_result}"
```

```json
{
  "DataInterval": 300,
  "EndTime": "2022-07-25T15:15:00Z",
  "HttpCodeData": {
    "UsageData": [
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1659063600,
        "Value": {
          "CodeProportionData": [
            {
              "Code": "404",
              "Count": 36,
              "Proportion": 0.022
            },
            {
              "Code": "502",
              "Count": 3,
              "Proportion": 0.002
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "TimeStamp": 1659063900,
        "Value": {
          "CodeProportionData": [
            {
              "Code": "404",
              "Count": 27,
              "Proportion": 0.015
            },
            {
              "Code": "502",
              "Count": 5,
              "Proportion": 0.002
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "StartTime": "2022-07-25T15:10:00Z"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dfKKaFhqL28)

Note: If you wanted to include also `.StartTime` and `.EndTime`, just list them along on the LHS:

```
(.StartTime, .HttpCodeData.UsageData[].TimeStamp, .EndTime) |= fromdateiso8601
```

Comment: Can I apply `fromdate | strflocaltime("%Y:%m:%d%H:%M")`  instead of `fromdateiso8601` ? returns error if I just replace it.

Comment: To replace `fromdateiso8601` with more than one operation you have to wrap them in parentheses, e.g. `... |= (fromdate | strflocaltime("%Y:%m:%d%H:%M"))`